# Kendo Grid - Edit one cell and update selected cells

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Currently I am using Kendo Grid in editable mode where I want to select multiple cells from one of grid's column and if I make changes in last selected cell, that last changed value should get set to all selected cells.

I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple things in place to make this work

- grid

  - selectable: 'multiple, cell'
  - editable: true
  - toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"] (if remote data)
  - change event handler to store selected cells and put one of them in edit mode
  - save event handler to propagate edited value to selected cells
  - keydown event handler to detect enter key as an edit save action
- dataSource

  - batch mode (if remote data)

There may be some odd edge cases with respect to hyperactive fingers.

Check out this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/oLOxOcuf), which has this coding:

A grid with the event handlers coded inline in the configuration options

```
change: function (e) {
  selected = (this.select().length > 1) ? this.select() : null;
  if (selected) {
    this.editCell($(selected[selected.length-1]));
  }
},
save: function (e) {
  if (e.values) {
    for (var field in e.values) {
      // propogate edited field value to each selected
      for (var i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
        var uid = $(selected[i]).closest("tr").data("uid");
        var model = this.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
        model.set(field,e.values[field]);
      }

      // should be only one field
      break;
    }
  }
},
```

and enter key detection

```
$("#grid tbody").on("keydown", "tr", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    //get the pressed key code
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        $(e.srcElement).closest("tbody").focus();
        setTimeout(function () {
            grid.saveRow();
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You Richard. This helped me to set values but still I am getting one small issue. I am able to set value to Model field but in text input box value is not getting reflected. When I save changes with remote call, I am able to see updated value but not instantly. Also items not remains selected. Any help on this?

Comment: Would need a little more info, *save changes* is that using the toolbar ?  If not, you might need to use the datasource `sync` to cause the remote service specified in transport.update to occur.  The grid `saveChanges` is another way to sync the dataSource.

Comment: When datasource is configured as remote and batch, my understanding is that `model.set` should mark changed rows with a little red triangle indicating un-sync'ed changed fields.  The closure variable `selected` should maintain your selections if one or more of the methods causes the selections to be undone.  After manually syncing, you may have to invoke grid.select via setTimeout, using `selected` (or a copy thereof). In not manually, you will re select within some event handler.  Start a new question if any of these ideas don't pan out.  Happy codings!

Comment: Richard, Sorry for making confusion. As per your dojo, I am now able to set values to selected fields model. But change is not immediately appearing on cells(selected textboxes). Any help on this?